# Advantages and Disadvantages of Gaussian Elimination Over Iterative Methods.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having a hard time understanding the advantages and disadvantages of using Gaussian Elimination over other Iterative Methods such as the Jacobi iteration and what are the advantages of using partial pivoting vs not usual partial pivoting. Thanks!

Comment: A possible advantage of a LU or Cholesky factorisation is that, if you have multiple right hand sides, so only need to compute the factorization once. If I recall it correctly, such decompositions require more memory than iterative methods, which is a disadvantage.